# ARKit2 Marker Images and Assets On-Demand

Tags: arkit

I have built an app that works really well if all resources and assets are within the app for 2D Markers.

But now, I'd like to pull marker 2d images on-demand from server, then use the downloaded 2D images to play content related to specific images.

I am having a hard time finding a solution for this. Any ideas or feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage).

An example from their repo:

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader()
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/jpeg")!)

downloader.download(urlRequest) { response in
    print(response.request)
    print(response.response)
    debugPrint(response.result)

    if let image = response.result.value {
        print(image)
    }
}
```